# What does "eo" mean in this passage of Hyginus?

Tags: vocabulary, declension, hyginus

In his account of Œdipus, Hyginus writes:

> [Œdipus] fortissimus præter ceteros erat eique per invidiam æquales objiciebant eum subditum esse Polybo, eo quod Polybus tam clemens esset et ille impudens.

My attempt at a literal translation would read something like

> [Œdipus] was far stronger than the others, and out of envy his rivals would mock him, [saying] that he had been falsely substituted as Polybus' [son], since Polybus was so mild and he [so] shameless.

Mary Grant's translation in *The Fables of Hyginus* reads:

> [Œdipus] was courageous beyond the rest, and through envy his companions taunted him with not being Polybus’ son, since Polybus was so mild, and he so assertive.

So I see that my translation is more or less correct. But what I don't understand is how *eo* is working in *eo quod Polybus tam clemens esset it ille impudens*. Both my translation and Grant's seem to ignore it.

Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if *eo* is doing anything. Wouldn't the passage make perfect sense without it? One could see it as a causal ablative, so that *eo quod* would mean *for the reason that*. It feels redundant with *quod*.

Comment: Yes, I think causal ablative must be right. "For that (reason), (namely) because..."

Comment: I'd buy that. Interestingly, however, I find that a poster at http://www.fisheaters.com/forums/index.php?topic=1591642.0 offers this advice (about a different passage): "'Eo quod' is a rather rare construction. It is a causal clause that is usually employed with the subjunctive to introduce a hypothetical reason." However, I have no idea who s/he is or whether this is right!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me expand my comment into an answer.

The most natural interpretation that occurs to me is that *eo* is the ablative of *id*.
This ablative is causal, meaning "for that reason".
I believe you could substitute *ea causa* if you wanted.

I would translate the passage as "…mocked him for the reason that Polybus…".
Here "for the reason" is *eo* and "that" is *quod*, roughly.
If there was no *eo*, I would translate it as "…mocked him since Polybus…".
Here *quod* means "since".

I find *eo quod* a somewhat unnatural construction.
One could argue that it is just Hyginus' (bad) style and ignore *eo* altogether, but I would not omit *eo*.

The word *eo* is not necessary but it does have a function:
it practically adds emphasis to *quod*.
The best translation is a matter of taste, but I think a bit of added emphasis preserves the spirit.
I am not a native speaker of English, so I will leave it for others to judge which English expression best captures the idea.

Comment: Thanks. So your thought is that *eo quod* is working sort of like e.g. *propterea quod*. I'll buy that, though I too find it an odd construction.

Comment: Pseudo-Hyginus!

Comment: @JoelDerfner, yes, *eo* seems to do the same as *propterea* here. I can't tell if there is something else behind it since it feels weird, but I don't know how else to make sense of it.

Comment: +1 for Pseudo-Hyginus. I've got dissertation material right here! I also find the phrase in a set of responses at http://www.divinumofficium.com/cgi-bin/horas/Pofficium.pl?date1=02-10-2013&command=prayMatutinum&version=Reduced%201955&testmode=seasonal&lang2=Latin&votive= : "Angelus Domini vocavit Abraham, dicens:
* Ne extendas manum tuam super puerum, eo quod timeas Dominum."

Answer (score 3):

The meaning is: "[it is] because of this that ...". An earlier contributor was right to say that eo ("because of this", and yes it is an ablative) adds emphasis. The Latin is poorer without it.